# Why are identical sections different heights?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have a layout with 4 sections, each containing an aside and a main that take up half the screen. Aside starts on the left for the first section, then moves to the left for the second, alternating each for. I have made copies of the first sections html for each of the next. I used the flex property "order" to change the position of the aside/main containers. All css applied is being applied evenly amongst the sections, so theres no reason any section should be different. However when I use Jquery's height() method, the first mains height returns 1252(px) while the next three return 1216. What could possibly be making the first section taller than the following 3?.

Pen: https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/QgXoMr

```js
// two functions, one changes to fixed 


var windw = this;


$.fn.startFixed = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos + 200
            });
        }
    });
};



// this one changes to absolute

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};


// some values to start and stop points

var asideHeight = $(".aside").height();
var stopPoint = asideHeight - 303; 

var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();



$('.container-text').followTo(stopPoint);


 

// trying to put jquery objects in variables but coming back undefined in console


var firstPos = $(".container-text").position();
var firstPosAt = $(".container-text").css('position');

var secondPos = $("#section2").position();
var secondPosAt = $("#section2").css("position");

var thirdPos = $("#section3").position();
var thirdPosAt = $("#section3").css("position");

var lastPos = $("#lastFixed").position();
var lastPosAt = $("#lastFixed").css('position');

var secHeight = $("#main2").height();
var secHeight1 = $(".main").height();


//first section height = 1252
console.log(secHeight1); 

// second and following 2 = 1216... why?
console.log(secHeight); 



console.log(firstPos);
console.log(firstPosAt);
console.log(secondPos); 
console.log(secondPosAt); 
console.log(thirdPos); 
console.log(thirdPosAt); 
console.log(lastPos); 
console.log(lastPosAt);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;  
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

section:nth-child(even) main {
  order: -1;
}

aside,main {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

aside{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
    justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

aside {
  padding: .5em;
}


.container-content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

article {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 75px;
}

.container-text{
    position: fixed;
}

#section2{
  position: absolute;
 
}
#section3{
  position: absolute;
}
#lastFixed{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div class="container-text">
          <header class="hello">Hello</header>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="main">
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
    <section>
      <aside id="aside2">
        <div id="section2">
          <p class="hello">Hello</p>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main id="main2">
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
    <section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div id="section3">
          <p class="hello">Hello</p>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main>
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
    <section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div id="lastFixed">
          <p class="hello">Hello</p>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main>
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First Heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy is because you have an extra line of text in the `<article>` under the 'Second heading' of the first `.container-content`.

The article in the first `.container-content` is:

```
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.
</article>
```

This has the additon of `Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.` at the end.

All the others `article` elements contain only:

```
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
</article>
```

Comment: Do you have any Idea why there would be a difference between my pen, which has matching heights, and my local live preview in latest chrome? I made the change to both, and the code was copy pasted from my pen. However now my  first section's height dropped to 1200(px). With the others remaining at 1216. My pen section heights are all 1216.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose issues that I can't see, however a 16px difference would make me think there's a line break, or extra line of text somewhere. The easiest way to find the difference (and how I found the above) is to go through each element in the DOM inspector and compare their heights. You'll find at least one child where the height is different, and from there it should be easy to spot why

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. There's a padding on the aside elements and I was measuring the size of the section by the aside's height. Thank you though.